# Roll join with no duplicates in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two tables coming from devices that gather data with different sampling frequencies. One device samples every 30 seconds, the other is roughly 30 and sometimes drops measurements (example sequence might be `31, 61, 95, 151`, notice how it missed the sample around ~120). My original `data.frame` contains a `datetime` instead of the number of seconds but the toy data should work to illustrate.

```
q1 <-
read.table(text="
           A    0   1.1
           A    30  1.2
           A    90  1.3
           A    120 1.4
           B    15  -5
           B    45  -3
           B    75  -3.5
           C    10  0
           C    40  -1.4
           C    70  -1")

q2 <-
  read.table(text="
           A    10  10.1
           A    40  10.2
           A    110 10.4
           B    30  -50
           B    90  -30
           C    5   0
           C    35  -10.4
           C    76  -10")

names(q1) <- c("key","datetime","x")
names(q2) <- c("key","timepoint","y")

# create a joint_time to keep the originals in place
q1$joint_time <- q1$datetime
q2$joint_time <- q2$timepoint
```

If I try to join by nearest, I get

```
# set the keys
data.table::setkey(data.table::setDT(q1), key, joint_time)
data.table::setkey(data.table::setDT(q2), key, joint_time)

q2[q1, roll="nearest"]
```

Notice the duplicates on row 4 and 6.

```
    key timepoint     y joint_time datetime    x
 1:   A        10  10.1          0        0  1.1
 2:   A        40  10.2         30       30  1.2
 3:   A       110  10.4         90       90  1.3
 4:   A       110  10.4        120      120  1.4
 5:   B        30 -50.0         15       15 -5.0
 6:   B        30 -50.0         45       45 -3.0
 7:   B        90 -30.0         75       75 -3.5
 8:   C         5   0.0         10       10  0.0
 9:   C        35 -10.4         40       40 -1.4
10:   C        76 -10.0         70       70 -1.0
```

My ideal output would join by nearest but fill with `NA` instead of duplicate on `y` values.

```
    key timepoint     y joint_time datetime    x
 1:   A        10  10.1          0        0  1.1
 2:   A        40  10.2         30       30  1.2
 3:   A       110  10.4         90       90  1.3
 4:   A        NA    NA        120      120  1.4
 5:   B        30 -50.0         15       15 -5.0
 6:   B        NA    NA         45       45 -3.0
 7:   B        90 -30.0         75       75 -3.5
 8:   C         5   0.0         10       10  0.0
 9:   C        35 -10.4         40       40 -1.4
10:   C        76 -10.0         70       70 -1.0
```

I'm fine with doing the join first and then finding the duplicates and changing them to NA. I will later try to interpolate the `y` variable there. Not sure if there's a direct way to do the join and fill with `NA` or if it has to be done a posteriori.

Comment: These would have to be separate steps. Rows 4 and 6 _are_ unique - they have different keys.

Comment: @Cole Happy to do it in two steps, any suggestions? Rows are unique, values on `y` are duplicated.

Comment: ```res[duplicated(res, by = c('timepoint', 'y')) | duplicated(res, by = c('timepoint', 'y'), fromLast = TRUE), `:=`(timepoint = NA_real_, y = NA_real_)]``` I think.

Comment: A slight modification, `res[duplicated(res, by = c('timepoint', 'y')),
    `:=`(timepoint = NA_real_, y = NA_real_)]` seems to work in this particular case. But how would this behave if the same `y` value appeared later on the `data.frame` not because it was put there buy the roll, but because it really happen in the data. It's not safe to assume this will work, would it be better to create some sort of `sample_number` identifier and look for duplicates of the combination of `sample_number`, `timepoint` and `y` ?

Comment: You should include that scenario in the sample data. But yes, overall you would need an identifier to indicate that the result was from the join. I forget how rolling joins work with non-matches, but you could potentially look for ```is.na(key)``` along with the duplicated call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, I don't think it's awesome but as far as I can see, it is working as expected.

```
q1$joint_time <- q1$datetime
q2$joint_time <- q2$timepoint
# create a sample id using the key since the data is grouped
q2$sample_id <- paste0(q2$key, as.character(1:nrow(q2)))

# Join
res <- q2[q1, roll="nearest"]
# fill with NAs
res %>% mutate_at(vars(y,timepoint), ~ifelse(duplicated(sample_id), NA, .))
```

Which produces

```
    key timepoint     y joint_time sample_id datetime    x
 1:   A        10  10.1          0        A1        0  1.1
 2:   A        40  10.2         30        A2       30  1.2
 3:   A       110  10.4         90        A3       90  1.3
 4:   A        NA    NA        120        A3      120  1.4
 5:   B        30 -50.0         15        B4       15 -5.0
 6:   B        NA    NA         45        B4       45 -3.0
 7:   B        90 -30.0         75        B5       75 -3.5
 8:   C         5   0.0         10        C6       10  0.0
 9:   C        35 -10.4         40        C7       40 -1.4
10:   C        76 -10.0         70        C8       70 -1.0
```